# Express.js - Check if user already followed and show unfollow button

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loops, express, ejs

I have successfully made it so that users can follow each other. What happens when you click Follow is that it will push your user id to the followers of the user you click follow on and then it will push the id of the user you are clicking follow on in the current users following section.

Now i am trying to make it so that when you enter a profile page it will display "Follow" if you don't follow the user and "unfollow" if you already follow. I am trying to make it loop through the users followers to see if one of the id's match with the current users id. But no matter what i do i am not able to get the correct result.

My route for watching a user-profile is:

```
router.get("/profile/:id", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    User.findById(req.params.id).populate("followers").exec(function(err, foundUser) {
        if (err) {
            req.flash("error", "Ooops! Seems like there are no users with this id.");
            res.redirect("back");
        }
        else {
            Mappin.find().where("author.id").equals(foundUser._id).exec(function(err, foundMappins) {
                if (err) {
                    req.flash("error", "Something went wrong trying to find the map markers from this user.");
                    res.redirect("back");
                }
                else {
                    Blogpost.find().where("author.id").equals(foundUser._id).exec(function(err, foundBlogposts) {
                        if (err) {
                            req.flash("error", "Something went wrong trying to find the blogposts from this user.");
                            res.redirect("back");
                        }
                        else {
                            Post.find().where("author.id").equals(foundUser._id).exec(function(err, foundPosts) {
                                if (err) {
                                    req.flash("error", "Something went wrong trying to find the posts from this user.");
                                    res.redirect("back");
                                }
                                else {
                                    res.render("webapplication/user/userprofile", { user: foundUser, mappin: foundMappins, blogpost: foundBlogposts, post: foundPosts });
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

And when i am trying to check if the user is already following i am doing the following in my user views:

```
                                <% user.followers.forEach(function(follower) { %>
                                <% if(currentUser && follower._id.equals(currentUser._id)){  %>
                                    <div class="Button-Collection">
                                        <a href="/profile/<%= user.id %>/follow" class="Button Add" title="Unfollow <%= user.firstName %>">Unfollow</a>
                                    </div>
                                <% } %>
                                <% if (currentUser && !follower._id.equals(currentUser._id)) { %>
                                    <div class="Button-Collection">
                                        <a href="/profile/<%= user.id %>/follow" class="Button Add" title="Follow <%= user.firstName %>">Follow</a>
                                    </div>
                                <% } %>
                                <% }); %>
```

My userSchema:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    avatar: String,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: { type: String, unique: true },
    resetPasswordToken: String,
    resetPasswordExpires: Date,
    gender: String,
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    comments: [ // Allows users to comment on business profiles and allows businesses to showcase their comments
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Comment"
        }
    ],
    posts: [ // Allows users to comment on business profiles and allows businesses to showcase their comments
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Post"
        }
    ],
    followers: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }],
    following: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }],
    blogPosts: [ // Allows admins to see and write blogposts for the website
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Blogpost"
        }
    ],
    mapPins: [ // Allows admins to see and write blogposts for the website
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Mappin"
        }
    ],
    businessLocations: String,
    businessBiography: String,
    businessLogo: String,
    businessName: String,
    businessWebsite: String,
    businessFacebook: String,
    businessTwitter: String,
    businessYoutube: String,
    businessLinkedin: String,
    isAdmin: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    isBusiness: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    isUser: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    facebookId: String,
    facebookToken: String,
    facebookEmail: String,
    googleId: String,
    googleToken: String,
    googleEmail: String
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

I have also tried with for(var i = 0; i < user.followers.length; i++), but that doesn't get me the result as well.

I really hope one of you are able to help me solve this riddle since i can't figure this out on my own.

Comment: can you post you `User` schema? Also check the edit in case the closing `</div>` was part of your problem.

Comment: Callback helllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll!

Comment: @dimitristseggenes - I have now added my user schema also.

Answer (score 0):

Michael, try to use == to compare the ids:

follower._id == currentUser._id

Comment: I tried what you mentioned, but unfortunately it gave me both a follow button and an unfollow button. I think its because it loops though and if one of the ids doesn't match it gives an unfollow button and when it finds one that match it gives a follow button. No matter if i use for loop or if i use for.each it displays a button on each id in the array and not only once.